# AFNetworking 2.0 with NSProgress - Multiple Files

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I'm interested in replacing some old AFNetworking 1.0 code with 2.0 using NSProgress. Here is a sketch of what I'm thinking of...

```
NSProgress *overallProgress = [NSProgress progressWithTotalUnitCount:[requests count]];
for (NSURLRequest *request in requests) {
   [overallProgress becomeCurrentWithPendingUnitCount:1];
   [self downloadTask:request];
   [overallProgress resignCurrent];
}

- (void)downloadTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
   NSProgress *progress = nil;
   NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [self.sessionManager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:&progress destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
   } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
   }];
}
```

I've read several posts on this and I'm having trouble composing the sub-tasks progress with the overallProgress. Getting progress back for a single file works, but trying to compose NSProgress tasks under and umbrella task eludes me.

How can I create an overall task with N pieces and then have each file as its download update the overall task?

Comment: No, I moved on because the issue was a nice-to-have and not a must-have feature. We ended up with per-file granularity rather than per byte.

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know. Per file might work for us too.